# How do I find an error in the while loop?

Tags: dart

I need help. I wrote the code and checked it a hundred times. But I can't find the error. All code before the **while** loop works without errors. Error in the loop itself. When you run it, you get an infinite loop.

I would be grateful if you could tell me where I made the mistake and why it turns out to be an infinite loop.

```
class Semis {
  int i;
  double k;

  Semis(this.i, this.k);
}

void main() {
  var p = [
    0, 1, 5, 8, 9, 10, 17, 17, 20, 24, // 0X's
    30, 32, 35, 39, 43, 43, 45, 49, 50, 54, // 1X's
    57, 60, 65, 68, 70, 74, 80, 81, 84, 85, // 2X's
    87, 91, 95, 99, 101, 104, 107, 112, 115, 116, // 3X's
    119, 121, 125, 129, 131, 134, 135, 140, 143, 145, // 4X's
    151
  ];

  Function cutLog = (List p, int n) {
    // Some array to store calculated values
    num sum = 0;
    int iter = 0;
    int stock = n;
    List<Semis> pL = [];

    var map = Map.fromIterable(p,
        key: (index) => p.indexOf(index),
        value: (item) => item / (p.indexOf(item) > 0 ? p.indexOf(item) : 1));
    var sortedMap = Map.fromEntries(
        map.entries.toList()..sort((e1, e2) => e2.value.compareTo(e1.value)));

    sortedMap.forEach(
        (i, k) => pL.isEmpty || pL.last.i > i ? pL.add(Semis(i, k)) : null);

    while (stock > 0) {
      if ((stock - pL[iter].i) > 0) {
        sum = sum + p[pL[iter].i];
        stock = stock - pL[iter].i;
      } else
        iter++;
    }

    return sum; // Good luck intern!
  };
  print(cutLog(p, 5));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get an infinite loop because the condition of the loop never fails.

The condition is that `stock > 0`. However, what you do in the loop is:

- If `stock` minus some value is `>0`, you decrement `stock`. Therefore `stock` remains higher than `0`
- Else you increment the iterator.

You never actually allow `stock` to be decremented enough so that it becomes `0`. I think your `if` comparison should be made using `>= 0`, if that seems logical for your algorithm. If not, then you probably need to rework it more.

Comment: Thank you. An elementary error, but the more I looked at the loop, the more I didn't notice it. It happens...

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the list of `Semis` you create, its last element is `Semis(0, 0.0)`.

That means that your loop, will eventually reach this, and then

```dart
  if ((stock - pL[iter].i) > 0) {
        sum = sum + p[pL[iter].i];
        stock = stock - pL[iter].i;
```

will do nothing because `pL[iter].i` is zero.

You probably need to bail out of the loop at this point.

Your loop will, as [Lyubomir Vasilev says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65033265/2156621), never have a false condition because `stock` never reaches zero. Your `iter` is increment, and if it hadn't been for the `Semis(0, _)` entry, you would eventually have run past the end of the `pL` array and gotten an index-out-of-range error. With that zero-value in the loop, you will run forever.

Comment: Thank you. An elementary error, but the more I looked at the loop, the more I didn't notice it. It happens...